# Magento product quantity wise price increase

Tags: magento, product

I want to create only one product in magento whose total price will be $50 more for any quantity less than 100 and $35 more for any quantity more than 100 while being added to cart.I have tried price rules but it seems to be not working.Please help me how do i create it.The product also includes additional parameters like tier pricing

These are the tier prices
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a singled product and add tier pricing for it.
Magento knowledge base shows how to do it: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

Comment: i have already added tier pricing but except this i want an increased amount of $30 and $50 to the total amount not for single product.eg if i am buying 75 products of total amount of $100 after deducting the tier price,I have to pay $150 as quantity is less than 100.If greater than 100 i have to pay $35 more

Comment: can you share a print screen of your product tier pricing?

Comment: 30 cards  ..................... $1.75 each
50 cards  ..................... $1.45 each
75 cards  ..................... $1.40 each
100 cards  ..................... $1.35 each
150 cards  ..................... $1.30 each
200  cards +  ..................... $1.25 each

Comment: why don't you add the amount you want to be incremented by in these tier prices?

Comment: i want the amount constant for the cart not for individual